# Improved inequality (theorem 5) chapter 7 Evans book

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

This is the second step improved regularity (theorem 5) in Evans' book chapter 7.

> step   2.   Combining the above inequalities, we deduce
> $$||u_m'||_{L^2(U)}^2+\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}A[u_m,u_m])\leq \frac{C}{\epsilon}(||u_m||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(U)}^2)+2\epsilon||u_m'||_{L^2(U)}^2.$$
> Choosing $\epsilon=\frac{1}{4}$ and integrating , we find
> $$\int_{0}^{T}||u_m'||_{L^2(U)}^2dt+\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} A[u_m(t), u_m(t)]\leq C(A[u_m(0),u_m(0)])+\int_{0}^{T}||u_m||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(U)}^2dt\leq C(||g||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))^2}),$$
> according to theorem 2 in $\S$ 7.1.2, where we esimated $||u_m(0)||_{H_0^1(U)}\leq ||g||_{H_0^1(U)}$ . As $A[u,u]\geq \theta\int_{U}|Du|^2dx$ for each $u\in H_0^1(U),$ we find that
> $$\sup_{0\leq t\leq T}||u_m(t)||_{H_0^1(U)}^2\leq C(||g||_{H_0^(U)}+||f||_{L^2(0,T;L^2(U))}).$$
> Passing to limits as $m=m_l \rightarrow\infty$, we deduce that $u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H_0^1(U))$, $u'\in L^2(0,T;L^2(U)),$ with the stated bounds; cf. Problem 6 . $\cdots$

My doubts:1. Why the inequality $$\int_{0}^{T}||u_m'||_{L^2(U)}^2dt+\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} A[u_m(t), u_m(t)]\leq C(A[u_m(0),u_m(0)])+\int_{0}^{T}||u_m||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(U)}^2dt $$ holds ?

From the book, I can get: $$\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} (\int_{0}^{t}||u_m'||_{L^2(U)}^2dt+A[u_m(t), u_m(t)]) \leq C(A[u_m(0),u_m(0)])+\int_{0}^{T}||u_m||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(U)}^2dt $$ and $$\sup_{0\leq t\leq T} A[u_m(t), u_m(t)]\leq  C(A[u_m(0),u_m(0)])+\int_{0}^{T}||u_m||_{H_0^1(U)}^2+||f||_{L^2(U)}^2dt$$
2. Why the inequality $||u_m(0)||_{H_0^1(U)}\leq ||g||_{H_0^1(U)}$ hold? While in theorem 2 , $||u_m(0)||_{L^2(U)}\leq ||g||_{L^2(U)}$ does hold.

Could someone give me some advice , thank you!